# Evaluate the directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The question states:

> Evaluate the directional derivative of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+3z^2$ at $(1,1,0)$ in the direction of $\vec i - \vec j +2\vec k$.

I learned that $f'(\vec a; \vec y) = \nabla f(\vec a)\cdot \vec y$. Now $\nabla f(\vec a)$ is the gradient vector, which has components $(D_1f(\vec a), ..., D_n f(\vec a))$.

Therefore I first calculated the gradient vector by calculating each partial derivative, and I obtained $\nabla f(\vec x) = (2x, 4y, 6x)$. I then substituted in $(1,1,0)$ and obtained $\nabla f(1,1,0) = (2, 4, 0)$. Finally, taking the dot product with $(1,-1,2)$, I obtained $f'((1,1,0); (1,-1, 2)) = -2$. However, the answer I am given is $-2/\sqrt 6$. What am I doing wrong?
The theorem I am given, with proof, states: Assume $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$ with total derivative $T_a$. Then the derivative $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ exists for every $\vec y$ in $R^n$ and we have $$T_a(\vec y) = f'(\vec a; \vec y)$$. Moreover, $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ is a linear combination of the components of $y$. In fact, if $y = (y_1, ..., y_n$, we have $$f'(\vec a; \vec y)=\sum^n_{k=1}D_kf(\vec a)y_k$$. This can be written as a dot product: $\nabla f(\vec a)\cdot y$.

The proof is as follows:
The first formula holds trivially if $\vec y = \vec O$ since both $T_a(\vec O) = 0$ and $f'\vec a; \vec O = 0$.Therefore we can assume that $\vec y \neq \vec O$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$ we have a Taylor formula,
$$f(\vec a + \vec v) = f(\vec a) + T_a(\vec v) + ||\vec v||E(\vec a, \vec v)$$
for $||\vec v|| < r$ for some $r>0$, where $E(\vec a, \vec v)\rightarrow 0$ as $||\vec v|| \rightarrow 0$. In this formula we take $\vec v = h\vec y$, where $h\neq 0$ and $|h|~ ||\vec y||<r$. Then $||\vec v|| < r$. Since $T_a$ is linear we have $T_a(\vec v) = T_a(h\vec y) = hT_a(\vec y)$. Therefore the above Taylor formula gives us 
$$\frac{f(\vec a + h\vec y)-f(\vec a)}{h}=T_a(\vec y) + \frac{|h| ~ ||\vec y||}{h}E(\vec a, \vec v).$$
Since $||\vec v|| \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ and since $|h|/h = ±1$, the right-hand member of the above equation tends to the same limit $T_a(\vec y)$ as $h\rightarrow0$. Therefore the left-hand member tends to the same limit. This proves the theorem's first formula.

Now we use the linearity of $T_a$ to deduce the second formula. If $\vec y = (y_1,...,y_n)$ we have $\vec y = \sum^n_{k=1}y_k\vec{e_k}$, hence
$$T_a(\vec y) = T_a(\sum^n_{k=1}y_k\vec{e_k})=\sum^n_{k=1}y_kT_a(\vec {e_k})=\sum^n_{k=1}y_kf'(\vec a; \vec {e_k})=\sum^n_{k=1}y_kD_kf(\vec a).$$

Comment: The directional derivative should be $\nabla f(a) \cdot \frac{y}{|y|}$, so you need to normalize $y$, that is $\frac{y}{|y|} = \frac{(1,-1,2)}{\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2 + 2^2}} = \frac{(1,-1,2)}{\sqrt{6}}$

Comment: @Dayton The theorem I am given, with proof, states: Assume $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$ with total derivative $T_a$. Then the derivative $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ exists for every $\vec y$ in $R^n$ and we have $T_a(\vec y) = f'(\vec a; \vec y)$. Moreover, $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ is a linear combination of the components of $y$. In fact, if $y = (y_1, ..., y_n$, we have $f'(\vec a; \vec y)=\sum^n_{k=1}D_kf(\vec a)y_k$. This can be written as a dot product: $\nabla f(\vec a)\cdot y$.

Comment: I think this is just a matter of definitions. How did you define $f'(a;y)$? I'm sure the formula was defined as $f'(a;y) := \dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} f(a + ty)$ but did you require $y$ to be a unit vector? Some authors require $y$ to be a unit vector while others do not. So the answer to your question depends entirely on what definitions you are using

Comment: @peek-a-boo The formula was defined: Given a scalar field $f: S\rightarrow R$, where $\subseteq R^n$. Let $\vec a$ be an interior point of $S$ and let $\vec y$ be an arbitrary point in $R^n$. The derivative of $f$ at $\vec a$ with respect to $y$ is denoted by the symbol $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ and is defined by the equation $f'(\vec a; \vec y)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\vec a + h\vec y)-f(\vec a)}{h}$ when the limit on the right exists.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivative.html OR

Comment: Apparently there are two conflicting definitions of directional derivatives. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You said that you'd tell me where they rely on $\vec y$ being a unit vector in the proof though. Where is that so?

Comment: @JohnArg I did not know that there were conflicting definitions.With your definition whatever you have done is right. Personally I think directional derivative should depend only on the direction of the vector, not on the length, so I consider your defintion as non-standard and somewhat odd. But no mistake in what you have done and no mistake in the proof of the theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks a lot for your patience. But why does the answer key in my book say that the answer is $-2/\sqrt 6$ then? Is my answer right when using this definition? The book is Apostol Vol 2.

Comment: The answer given is wrong if the book is using your definition. I have  an old version of Apostol's book in which directional derivative is defined only when $y$ is a unti vector!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97377/discussion-between-john-arg-and-kavi-rama-murthy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula for the directional derivative is wrong. It is correct if $ y$ is a unit vector. In general you have to divide by the norm of the vector which is $\sqrt 6$ in this case.

It is worth observing that the directional derivative cannot depend on the length of the vector; it can only depend on the direction of the vector.

EDIT: there are conflicting definitions of directional derivatives (as I just discovered) and whatever you have done is right with your definition. The answer provided is based on a different definition.

Comment: The theorem I am given, with proof, states: Assume $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$ with total derivative $T_a$. Then the derivative $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ exists for every $\vec y$ in $R^n$ and we have $T_a(\vec y) = f'(\vec a; \vec y)$. Moreover, $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ is a linear combination of the components of $y$. In fact, if $y = (y_1, ..., y_n$, we have $f'(\vec a; \vec y)=\sum^n_{k=1}D_kf(\vec a)y_k$. This can be written as a dot product: $\nabla f(\vec a)\cdot y$.

Comment: This is wrong . There must an assumption in the proof that $y$ is a unit vector. If you can reproduce the proof here I can show you where you need this assumption.

Comment: I added it as an edit

Answer (score 1):

You should take the dot-product with the unit vector to get the direction, otherwise the magnitude gets varied.
So the unit vector in the direction of $ \vec{i} - \vec{j}+2\vec{k}$ is $$\frac{\vec{i}-\vec{j}+2\vec{k}}{\sqrt{1+1+4}}=\frac{\vec{i}-\vec{j}+2\vec{k}}{\sqrt{6}}$$

Now the dot-product becomes $\frac{-2}{\sqrt6}$.

Comment: The theorem I am given, with proof, states: Assume $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$ with total derivative $T_a$. Then the derivative $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ exists for every $\vec y$ in $R^n$ and we have $T_a(\vec y) = f'(\vec a; \vec y)$. Moreover, $f'(\vec a; \vec y)$ is a linear combination of the components of $y$. In fact, if $y = (y_1, ..., y_n$, we have $f'(\vec a; \vec y)=\sum^n_{k=1}D_kf(\vec a)y_k$. This can be written as a dot product: $\nabla f(\vec a)\cdot y$.